# SimpleBrowser - Clique em um botão de uma página Web

Tags: c#

Bom dia,

estou tentando carregar um arquivo online e enviar este arquivo carregado após clicar no botão. Tudo isso utilizando o SimpleBrowser. No entanto, de nenhuma forma consigo clicar nesse botão, acredito que algo do próprio site esteja impedindo o clique. Não sei como resolver. Estou precisando de alguma dica. Segue uma parte do código.

1) Salvo o arquivo no local necessário
2) Clico para Enviar (mas não carrega)

```
       browser.Find("input", FindBy.Name, "field(-manter-arquivo)").Value = sArquivo;
       browser.Find("form", FindBy.Id, "enviarpliForm").SubmitForm();
```